# Approximation of Hölder functions by Fourier series

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, limits-and-convergence

Let $Q$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbf R^N$ with smooth boundary. Let $f\in C^a(\overline{Q})$, $0<a<1$.

- Denote $\psi_k(x)$  normalized eigenfunctions and $\lambda_k$ eigenvalues ($k=0,1,2\dotsc$, $\lambda_0=0$, $\psi_0=1/\sqrt{|Q|}$)  such that
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  -\Delta \psi_k= \lambda_k \psi_k,&\text{ in } Q,\\  
  \dfrac{\partial \psi_k}{\partial n}=0,&\text{ on }\partial \Omega.
  \end{cases}$$
- Finally denote
  $$
  S_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\int_Q f\psi_k\operatorname{d\!}x\, \psi_k(x).
  $$

Under what (additional) conditions we can expect
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\lVert f-S_n\rVert_{C(\overline{Q})}=0\; ?
$$

Comment: I cerrected. Thank you.

Comment: This is not true in higher dimension, basicly because the sequence of eigenfunctions need not be uniformly bounded. An example of this situation is the Laplace Beltrami on the unit sphere $S^{N-1}$ of $\mathbb R^N$. The eigenfunctions are the spherical harmonics, if $k$ is the degree, the supnorm is like $k^{N-2}$ and the expansion converges in the supnorm if $f \in C^l$ with $l>(N-1)/2$.

Comment: That's the most interesting thing to me: for what $p$ one have $\sup\limits_Q |\psi_k(x)|\approx k^p$ ? if it’s already been found by someone

Comment: Please, quote my name if you reply to me, to let me receive a notification. If $-\Delta \psi_k=\lambda_k \psi_k$ then $(-\Delta)^\ell \psi_k=\lambda_k^\ell \psi_k$ and by elliptic estimates the norm of $\psi_k$ in the Sobolev space $H^{2\ell}$ is boounded by $\lambda_k^\ell$. Since $\lambda_k \approx k^{2/N}$ choosing $2\ell >N/2$ by Sobolev embedding you get a rough estimate in the sup norm. I am counting eigenvalues and eigenfunctions with multiplicity (in the comment before all spherical harmonics of degrre $k$ belong to the same $\lambda_k$).

Comment: @Giorgio-Metafune, I thought about Sobolev theorems, but settled on $\Vert grad \psi_k\Vert^2= \lambda_k$, althogh it was naturally to continue with
$\Vert\Delta \psi_k\Vert^2=\lambda_k^2$ and so on....

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: on the sphere, how does one argue that if $f\in C^l$ for large $l$ then the projections $\langle f, \psi_k\rangle$ is small for large $k$? Are you just using that $C^l$ embeds into $W^{l,2}$ on compacts?

Comment: @WillieWong I will answer later in the late afternoon....(UTC+1)

Comment: @WillieWong One argument is short but uses elliptic regularity. For $\psi \in C^{2\ell}$ write $\psi=\sum_k (\psi, \psi_k)\psi_k$ in $L^2$ and $$\Delta^\ell \psi=\sum_k (\Delta^\ell \psi, \psi_k)\psi_k=\sum_k (\psi, \Delta^\ell \psi_k)\psi_k=\sum_k \lambda^\ell_k ( \psi, \psi_k)\psi_k=\Delta^\ell (\sum_k (\psi, \psi_k)\psi_k).$$ This gives that the series yielding $\psi$ converges in $H^{2\ell}$, by elliptic regularity, and by Sobolev embedding uniformly, for $\ell$ large.

Comment: @WillieWong The other one I know uses more on spherical harmonics, zonals, sup-norm estimates. If you need, I can write down it.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune thanks, that's good enough. The first one you listed is exactly what I meant by "$C^l$ embeds into $W^{l,2}$ on compacts" in my previous comment. I also suspected there's another proof using finer details of how spherical harmonics behave; it is good to see that confirmed in your second answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hölder functions periodic with period 1 satisfy the Dini criterion
$$
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\vert u(x+t)- u(x)\vert}{t} dt<+\infty,
$$
thus their Fourier series are  uniformly convergent (towards $u$). On the other hand the Besov space
$$
B^\alpha_{\infty, \infty}
$$
is equal to the Hölder space $C^\alpha$ for $\alpha\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Everything is more or less clear in periodic case.. But I can't find a suitable reference in multidimensional case